# Having a hard time understanding "Probably Equals" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio, homekit

This project turns appliances and such On/off using Apples homekit and a node.js server on raspberry pi(https://github.com/KhaosT/HAP-NodeJS). So Light_accessory.js,when vaule is true(1), turns a lamp(relay) on using childprocces and wiring pi. It also needs to turn the lamp off(gpio write 7 1) when value is false(0). Iv tried adding "probably equals" to it so it also turns the lamp(relay) off. Attempting to add Two values resulted of me and a night of googling and syntax errors..
Iv spent way more time on this project than I would like to admit.. Quite simply the objective is very similar to a project I did a while back with php.

```
?php 
    if(isset($_GET['trigger']) && $_GET['trigger'] == 1) {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        exec('gpio write 7 0');
    }
    if(isset($_GET['trigger']) && $_GET['trigger'] == 2) {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        exec('gpio write 7 1');
    }
?>
```

..................................................................................................................................................................

This is where the gpio is set to low(gpio write 7 0) when value is true(1).

```
{
            cType: types.POWER_STATE_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: function(value) {
                exec('gpio write 7 0' + value,function(error, stdout, stderr) {}
                );
            },
            perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
            format: "bool",
            initialValue: false,
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Turn On the Light",
            designedMaxLength: 1
        }, {
```

How do you add

```
exec('gpio write 7 1'(error, stdout, stderr)
```

when value is 0 in javascript? That way the lamp(relay) turns OFF as well.

..................................................................................................................................................................

Crude overview of Light_accessory.js; The top part is mostly product description rather than actual function. "cType: types.POWER_STATE_CTYPE," under "OnUpdate:" Is where the magic happens.

..................................................................................................................................................................

Full Light_accessory script

```
// HomeKit types required
var types = require("./types.js")
var exports = module.exports = {};
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var execute = function(accessory, characteristic, value) {
    console.log("executed accessory: " + accessory + ", and characteristic: " + characteristic + ", with value: " + value + ".");
}

exports.accessory = {
    displayName: "Light 1",
    username: "1A:2B:3C:4D:5E:FF",
    pincode: "031-45-154",
    services: [{
        sType: types.ACCESSORY_INFORMATION_STYPE,
        characteristics: [{
            cType: types.NAME_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: null,
            perms: ["pr"],
            format: "string",
            initialValue: "Light 1",
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Bla",
            designedMaxLength: 255
        }, {
            cType: types.MANUFACTURER_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: null,
            perms: ["pr"],
            format: "string",
            initialValue: "Oltica",
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Bla",
            designedMaxLength: 255
        }, {
            cType: types.MODEL_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: null,
            perms: ["pr"],
            format: "string",
            initialValue: "Rev-1",
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Bla",
            designedMaxLength: 255
        }, {
            cType: types.SERIAL_NUMBER_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: null,
            perms: ["pr"],
            format: "string",
            initialValue: "A1S2NASF88EW",
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Bla",
            designedMaxLength: 255
        }, {
            cType: types.IDENTIFY_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: null,
            perms: ["pw"],
            format: "bool",
            initialValue: false,
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Identify Accessory",
            designedMaxLength: 1
        }]
    }, {
        sType: types.LIGHTBULB_STYPE,
        characteristics: [{
            cType: types.NAME_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: null,
            perms: ["pr"],
            format: "string",
            initialValue: "Light 1",
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Bla",
            designedMaxLength: 255
        }, {
            cType: types.POWER_STATE_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: function(value) {
                exec('gpio write 7 0' + value,function(error, stdout, stderr) {}
                );
            },
            perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
            format: "bool",
            initialValue: false,
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Turn On the Light",
            designedMaxLength: 1
        }, {
            cType: types.HUE_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: function(value) {
                console.log("Change:", value);
                execute("Test Accessory 1", "Light - Hue", value);
            },
            perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
            format: "int",
            initialValue: 0,
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Adjust Hue of Light",
            designedMinValue: 0,
            designedMaxValue: 360,
            designedMinStep: 1,
            unit: "arcdegrees"
        }, {
            cType: types.BRIGHTNESS_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: function(value) {
                console.log("Change:", value);
                execute("Test Accessory 1", "Light - Brightness", value);
            },
            perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
            format: "int",
            initialValue: 0,
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Adjust Brightness of Light",
            designedMinValue: 0,
            designedMaxValue: 100,
            designedMinStep: 1,
            unit: "%"
        }, {
            cType: types.SATURATION_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: function(value) {
                console.log("Change:", value);
                execute("Test Accessory 1", "Light - Saturation", value);
            },
            perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
            format: "int",
            initialValue: 0,
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Adjust Saturation of Light",
            designedMinValue: 0,
            designedMaxValue: 100,
            designedMinStep: 1,
            unit: "%"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: just use an if statement in your `onUpdate` function? what do you mean by "probably equals"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
            cType: types.POWER_STATE_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: function(value) {
                if(value == 1){
                    exec('gpio write 7 0')
                    setTimeout(function() {exec('gpio write 7 1')},250)

                }
                if(value == 0){
                    exec('gpio write 6 0')
                    setTimeout(function() {exec('gpio write 6 1')},250)
                }
            },
            perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
            format: "bool",
            initialValue: false,
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Turn On the Light",
            designedMaxLength: 1
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Fromm messing around with this package myself I did notice the value is 'true' or 'false' not 1 or 0

Try checking for true then write out the 1

`value == true ? 1 : 0`

As per request, here's using your example.

`{
            cType: types.POWER_STATE_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: function(value) {
                exec('gpio write 7 0 ' + (value == true ? 1 : 0) ,function(error, stdout, stderr) {}
                );
            },
            perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
            format: "bool",
            initialValue: false,
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Turn On the Light",
            designedMaxLength: 1
        }`

Comment: Could you show another example using the Light_accessory script? Im new to javascript.

Comment: Updated with an example.